# How to create a floating element over input type range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I need `span#a` to translate to the same position on where slider thumb is. I need to somehow use `transform: translateX(and_step_to_translate_here)`. So to say a bit easier, I need `span#a` to follow the track thumb. How can I do it?

```css
input {width: 90%;}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1"/><br/>
<span id="a">I'm following.</span>
```

Comment: span and other text elements usually being inline elements try to be at the endpoint of previous existing elements. The above example fails because the space required by the text is more than the available space and thus is appearing in the next line. In case you still want it to be at RHS, you can try `position: absolute` on the span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can suggest is to use input range `oninput` event to follow the value of the input and use a proportional `margin-left` with this `value`.

Here's the code you need:

```
$('input[type="range"]').on('input', function() {
  $('span#a').css('margin-left', parseInt($(this).val() - 10) > 0 ? parseInt($(this).val() - 10) + '%' : '0px');
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('input[type="range"]').on('input', function() {
  $('span#a').css('margin-left', parseInt($(this).val() - 10) > 0 ? parseInt($(this).val() - 10) + '%' : '0px');
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 90%;
}

span#a {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" />
<span id="a">I'm following.</span>
```

**Note:**

- This will update the `span` left margin to be proportional to value
  of the `range`, so it will be updating between `0%` to `100%`, which gives it the floating effect.
- In the following sample Demo, the `margin-left` value needs more
  adjusting so it will give a better result. The logic is there, but
  needs just some adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/2cc83shx/2/

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( '#rangeInput' ).on( 'change', function() {
        $( '#a' ).css({
            'transform': 'translateX(' + $(this).val() + 'px)'
        })
    })
})
```

I can help a bit. you can positioning it a bit better later from my fiddle. (here, I'm using jquery to select the element. you can use pure js to do this too)

*UPDATE

If you want it to follow whenever you drag the range, follow the code below

https://jsfiddle.net/2cc83shx/3/

Comment: Your solution is good but it doesn't work correctly when you make input wider. But thanks.